# Shell node: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, cron, pm2

I have a cron job that runs a shell script every minute. However I keep getting

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
restarting
nohup: failed to run command ‘npm’: No such file or directory
```

as an output.

I have tried installing pm2 globally but this doesnt work.

This is my Shell file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH: /home/dev/bin/npm
pID=$(pgrep -x "PM2") 

if [ -n "${pID}" ];
then
    #do nothing 
    echo $pID "already running. not restarting." 
else
    # start it 
    echo "restarting"
    nohup npm ./home/dev/public_node/server.js --production &
fi
```

It should start the server.js file through pm2?

Comment: Add a `PATH=$PATH:<pathToDirContainingPm2>` as second line. Find that directory by running `type pm2` in Terminal.

Comment: usually where is that? @MarkSetchell

Comment: Start Terminal and run `type pm2` and it will tell you the path.

Comment: I updated my file and now I get a different error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank @Florian Schlag for helping me reach the answer and giving me the correct answer. I have pasted my file below for reference. Please note that I had to change some files around but these can be deduced from output npm errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/home/<user>/bin/
NPM="`which npm`"

if [ "x" == "x$NPM" ]; then
    (>&2 echo "NPM not installed")
    exit 1
fi

pID=$(pgrep "PM2" -f) 

if  [ -n "${pID}" ];
then
    exit 0
else
    # start it 
    echo "restarting"
    nohup $NPM start ./<file path ton script> --production &
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You edited your previous question from not finding `pm2` to not finding `node`, but **one way** to solve this is by determine the full path of arbitrary tools like this:

```
NPM="`which npm`"

if [ "x" == "x$NPM" ]; then
    (>&2 echo "NPM not installed")
    exit 1
fi

# Run by using the variable like it's a regular command
# e.g.
nohup $NPM ./home/dev/public_node/server.js --production &
```

Comment: So I tried that and got ```which: no npm in (/usr/bin:/bin)
NPM not installed```
However when I run it in terminaI get the path?

Comment: Can you run `which npm` in your normal shell and post the output here? Also an output of `echo $PATH` would be helpful.

Comment: running it in shell I get:
```
which: no npm in (/usr/bin:/bin)
$PATH:
```
and in The terminal 
```
Which NPM: /home/ellisdev/bin/npm
Path: /home/devfloder/perl5/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/devfloder/.local/bin:/home/devfloder/bin
```

Comment: That's a little bit strange, because `/home/ellisdev/bin` is not on your `PATH` but it's found by `which`. Could you try accessing npm *hardcoded* like `nohup /home/ellisdev/bin/npm ...` in your script? Do you run the script under the same user i.e. is the cronjob configured for the same user running the shell, or do you configure the cron job with something like `sudo crontab -e`?

Comment: apologies '/home/ellisdev/bin' is the same as '/home/dev/bin', auto fill error, mybad

Comment: I believe it is the same user, they are managed by a third party so I wouldnt be able to change it.

Comment: I don't have a lot of ideas left, but try changing the follwing `PATH=$PATH: /home/dev/bin/npm` to `PATH=$PATH:/home/dev/bin/` (removing the whitespace and pointing to the bin directory. The `PATH` environment variable takes a set of directories, you assigned an executable. Hope it helps. Maybe someone else has more ideas. :)

Comment: good news, I get a new error, but his is an npm error now that i should be able to manage :)